# How do I determine the accuracy of this two-dimensional potential field?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, conceptual

To begin with this might more be a conceptual question than a programming one. I will not write my code below, but if you want to really see it you can take a look at this similar code [link](http://www.codeproject.com/articles/1087025/using-python-tosolve-computational-physics-proble). The code's not the important thing here, so don't get confused trying to understand everything all the physics (electrostatics).

Let's say I want to solve this problem. I know the values on the boundaries and I guess a initial solution on the rectangular grid inside these boundaries, see figure below.[image: Potential=10 on boundaries; potential=0 inside]
Potential=10 on boundaries; potential=0 inside

I know that eventually the field will converge to the same potential as the boundaries. If I let the program iterate long enough the whole area on the inside will also become yellow. The figure below shows an intermediate step towards equilibrium:

[image]

Now, in this project I am working on I am supposed to stop the simulation when the accuracy of the simulation is 1%. Is there a general definition of accuracy in these cases when working with a two dimensional grid? There are several grid nodes, all with different values, are these supposed to be 1% or less from equilibrium (all yellow)?

(This might be the wrong forum, I am aware of that.)

Best regards

Comment: Are you aware of https://physics.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Yes I am, that might be a better forum.